# allow only numbers to continue using while & scanf

Tags: c

I am making a program where at the beginning it says please enter any number to continue. I want to restrict the input of characters. I tried to use the code showed below, however once I input another key instead of numbers, the process repeats indefinitely, it does not let me input a key the second time.

Considering that option is declared as int, here is the logic I was working with:

```
option = 0;
while(option < 1 || option > 9)
{
    printf("\nPlease press any number to continue and press enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help: The solution I used was puting an flushing the standard input at the end of the loop. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `scanf` fails due to the input not being a number, the input remains in the stream. So when you hit the next iteration of the loop, it reads the same thing and fails again in the same way.

Instead you should take some other action when the input fails, e.g.

```
if ( scanf("%d", &option) != 1 )
{
    printf("You didn't enter a number.\n");
    break;
}
```

In this situation you may also want to flush the input (i.e. discard the bogus characters). Presumably the bogus characters were input by someone typing them and press Enter, so you just read and discard all characters up until a newline. One way of doing this (there are several, including fancy `scanf` format strings) is:

```
for ( int ch; (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'; ) { }
```

Comment: I used fflush(stdin) and it works now. Thanks. 

The final code I used:

    option = 0;
    while(option < 1 || option > 9)
        {
        printf("\nPlease press any number (except 0) to continue and press enter: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        fflush(stdin);
            ;

    }

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour, my suggestion is standards-compliant

Answer (score 2):

This "else" that you used does not make sense. You only use the "else" keyword after an "if".

Just remove the else, and the program should work.

Comment: THanks for the reply. Sorry I putted the code wrong, it is actually without the else, the reason the else was there is because I tried to put an if before to try to reinforce the restriction, but it didn't worked. 

I removed the else anyways, left the loop as it is. It stills does the same, if I put a character instead of a number, the loop becomes endless, it doesn't let me input a new character, and prints "Please press any number to continue and press enter: " forever

Answer (score 0):

What Is The meaning of `else` here ? We can't see any `if` commands here :/
You also need to add this part after `scanf("%d", &option);`

```
scanf("\n");
```

because, after you entered a number, it gets the EOF. then it compares the EOF. so it will loop forever.

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed it. However the problem still persists.

Comment: I Edited my answer. check it out.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` consumes only the input that matches the format string, returning the number of characters consumed. Any character that doesn't match the format string causes it to stop scanning and leaves the invalid character still in the buffer.

You need to flush the invalid character out of the buffer before you proceed. This is a pretty dirty fix, but it will remove the offending characters from the output.

Try this program-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
        int option = 0;
        char c = 0;
        printf("\nPlease press any number to continue and press enter: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        while(option >=1 && option <= 9){
                printf("\nPlease press any number to continue and press enter: ");

                if (scanf("%d", &option) == 0) { //consume non-numeric chars from buffer
                        printf("Please Enter a number\n");
                        do {
                                c = getchar();
                        }
                        while (!isdigit(c));
                }
                else
                        // do your stuff here
                        ;
        }
        return 0;
}
```